# Query difference: Grouped JOIN vs inline JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, difference

I have two different queries which return the same data:

```
+---------+-------------------------------+----------+
| title   | body                          | username |
+---------+-------------------------------+----------+
| Welcome | You got a cool forum here     | john     |
| Welcome | Great topics.                 | boyd     |
| Welcome | Nice to have you as members   | cris     |
| Looking | I have the time and knowlegde | boyd     |
| Looking | I'm fully qualified for this  | joe      |
+---------+-------------------------------+----------+
```

Query I:

```
SELECT posts.title,comments.body,users.username
FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN (
        users INNER JOIN comments ON users.id = comments.user_id
    ) ON posts.id = comments.post_id
```

Query II:

```
SELECT posts.title,comments.body,users.username
FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id
    INNER JOIN users  ON users.id = comments.user_id
```

And these are my tables:

```
    USERS
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | john     |
|  2 | boyd     |
|  3 | ella     |
|  4 | cris     |
|  5 | joe      |
|  6 | esses    |
| 18 | test2    |
+----+----------+
            POSTS
+----+-----------------------+
| id | title                 |
+----+-----------------------+
|  1 | Welcome               |
|  2 | Looking for moderator |
+----+-----------------------+

                        COMMENTS
+---------+---------+------------------------------------------+
| post_id | user_id | body                                     |
+---------+---------+------------------------------------------+
|       1 |       1 | You got a cool forum here                |
|       1 |       2 | Great topics.                            |
|       1 |       4 | Nice to have you as members              |
|       2 |       2 | I have the time and knowlegde to do this |
|       2 |       5 | I'm fully qualified for this job         |
+---------+---------+------------------------------------------+
```

My question is: **Whats the real difference between these two queries?**

**EDIT:** This is the  EXPLAIN EXTENDED results:

Query I:

-- EXPLAIN EXTENDED

```
+----+-------------+----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | posts    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 |    2 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | comments | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 |    5 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | app.comments.user_id |    1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

-- SHOW WARNINGS

```
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select `app`.`posts`.`title` AS `title`,`app`.`comments`.`body` AS `body`,`app`.`users`.`username` AS `username` from `app`.`posts` left join (`app`.`users` join `app`.`comments`) on(((`app`.`posts`.`id` = `app`.`comments`.`post_id`) and (`app`.`users`.`id` = `app`.`comments`.`user_id`))) where 1 |
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Query II:

-- EXPLAIN EXTENDED

```
+----+-------------+----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | comments | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 |    5 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | app.comments.user_id |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | posts    | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 |    2 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

-- SHOW WARNINGS

```
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select `app`.`posts`.`title` AS `title`,`app`.`comments`.`body` AS `body`,`app`.`users`.`username` AS `username` from `app`.`posts` join `app`.`comments` join `app`.`users` where ((`app`.`posts`.`id` = `app`.`comments`.`post_id`) and (`app`.`users`.`id` = `app`.`comments`.`user_id`)) |
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't think there's any difference.

Comment: Run EXPLAIN EXTENDED...; followed by SHOW WARNINGS; on both queries

Comment: @Strawberry,@Barmar .  I just added the explain extended results. It looks like the first query performs 1 less extra query.

Comment: And SHOW WARNINGS; ?? Incidentally, for SO, I like to run EXPLAIN EXTENDED (and EXPLAIN) with the '\G' delimiter.

Comment: @Strawberry. SHOW WARNINGS added.  (I ran show warnings again after the first time and I get 'empty set'). Anyways. Which is the best query?

Comment: So, we can see that one query uses an outer join. The other one doesn't!

Comment: In general the first can have NULL non-POSTS column values. But if certain constraints hold then it can't and the results will always be the same. If you are concerned with difference in results in your situation then you need to tell us all constraints limiting the simultaneous values of the tables (including NOT NULL, PK, UNIQUE, FK) (whether you declare them or not).

Answer (score 1):

Join are processed logically from left to right unless you overwrite it using parentheses.

```
Q1: posts LEFT (users INNER comments)
```

`posts` is left join to the result of `(users INNER comments)`, which results in all rows from `posts` with NULLs where the join condition does not evaluate to `TRUE`

```
Q2: posts LEFT comments INNER users
```

Now `posts` is left joined to `comments` first, and columns from `comments` which could not be joined are NULLed. This result is then joined to `users` using an inner join. But due to the NULLs in `comments.user_id` the rows which have been added due to the outer join are removed again. In fact this is the same as inner joining all three tables.

Comment: So there is no difference between these queries other than syntactical ?

Comment: @boyd: Of course there is, it's a different result set. But only **you** knows which one is correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

there is no conceptual difference between these two queries but in order to improve performance its better to narrow temporal results table as soon as possible by joining bigger tables first and select only needed fields not all of them.

Comment: this is depend on size of your table. you must predict table size and based on that write your query

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm right in saying that query 2 is functionally identical to this:

```
select p.title
 , c.body
, u.username
 from posts p
 join comments c
 on p.id = c.post_id
 join users u
  on u.id = c.user_id
```

Whereas query 1 is identical to this

```
select p.title
 , c.body
 , u.username
 from posts p
join comments c
on p.id = c.post_id
 left 
 join users u 
on u.id = c.user_id
where 1
```

Comment: So there is only a syntactical difference?

Comment: No. Unless I'm mistaken (and I may be) there is a logical difference here. But it would be easy for you to demonstrate with your dataset